# java file reading file returning null

Tags: java, file

i have a method, which should return a string from a text file. But it returning null. Could you please help me to figure this one out? Thank you!
Here is the code

```
public String findFile()
{
    String line = "";

    try 
    {
        File myDir = new File("files");
        File myFile = new File(myDir, "ISBN 123-654.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
            System.out.println(line + "1");
        } 
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(line+"2");
    return line;
}
```

String line should hold a text like: H:\Java\workspace\LMS\files\book.jpg

many thanks to all participated! here is working code:

```
    public String findFile()
    {
        String line = "";
        try {
                File myFile = new File("files", "ISBN 123-654.txt");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) == null)  
                 System.out.println(line + "1");
                br.close();
             } 
             catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

    System.out.println(line+"2");
    return line;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to enter the absolute path for myDir?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what happens.

Comment: The `while` loop stops when `line == null`, since your function returns `line` after the loop you get `null`

Comment: Andi, yea, i tried so many ways of doing it... spent weekend and yesterday on it. This is the only way it actually reads file. Im newby in java btw

Comment: Why the extra set of brackets after you declare `line`? Also, note that this will not work if exported outside of Eclipse. Finally, why have that empty while loop? You could just write `line = br.readLine()` if you only have one line to handle.

Comment: WHOA!!!! pNre THATS IT!!! so easy... Thank you very much guys! all of you! Hugs!

Comment: yes nrubin29, you are right, ill fix it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop exits when `line` is null, thus the method returns null.

Assign the value of `line` to another variable in your loop (or concatenate each line, for example), and return this new variable.

For example, based on your code:

```
public String findFile(){
    String fileContent = "";

    try {
        File myDir = new File("files");
        File myFile = new File(myDir, "ISBN 123-654.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){ 
            System.out.println(line + "1");
            fileContent += line;
        } 
       }  
        catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(fileContent+"2");
    return fileContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop exists when the line is equal to null i.e line == null. So when you return the string line after the while loop, obviously it will return null.

Here you need to assign the last line to a variable and return that variable after the while loop exists.

```
public String findFile()
{
    String line = "";
    String rtLine = null;

    try 
    {
        File myDir = new File("files");
        File myFile = new File(myDir, "ISBN 123-654.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
            rtLine = line;
            System.out.println(line + "1");
        } 
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(line+"2");
    return rtLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple and fast is to use Google Guava:

```
try {
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(new File(PATH_TO_FILE), Charsets.UTF_8);
//return content lines separated by comma
return Joiner.on(",").join(lines);

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want last line:

```
try {
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(new File(PATH_TO_FILE), Charsets.UTF_8);
//return last line
if (lines.size() > 0) {
    return lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
} else {
    return null;
}

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i dont understand this code Adam, what is it doing and where i use it?

Comment: As I understand you want to read file content as a string. Files.readLines method returns lines from file as list of string. Then to make one string from them I use Joiner.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a `br.close();` at the end of the try block. This flushes the buffer and will give the data from the file.

Comment: While good practice, it shouldn't make a difference and is better left as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
File myFile = new File("files", "ISBN 123-654.txt");
```