# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, file

i have a working code for returning string from the file posted here
[java file reading file returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935589/java-file-reading-file-returning-null/22936464?noredirect=1#22936464)

now i have another problem to solve. Here is the code and my question below

```
public String findFile()
    {
        String bookId = "";
        blist = lRef.getBookArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < blist.size(); i++) {
            bookId =(blist.get(i).getIsbn());}
        String filenameToRead = bookId + ".txt";
        String path = "files";
    //  File folder = new File(path);       //im not using those yet as they wouldnt work   
    //  File infile = new File(path,filenameToRead);

        String line = "";
        try {
                File myFile = new File("files", "ISBN 123-654.txt");
                System.out.println(myFile);
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) == null) {          
                 br.close();}
             } 
             catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
    return line;
    }
```

im getting a name from arraylist which i use to build a file name here

```
String filenameToRead = bookId + ".txt";
```

if i print it out - it looks like this "ISBN 123-654.txt" (and it correct)
if i use `filenameToRead` in here instead of hardcode name of a file

```
File myFile = new File("files", filenameToRead );
```

it gives me a `FileNotFoundException`.
    Any ideas?

Comment: The .txt file would have to be in a `files` folder and this folder is in the current directory.

Comment: Do you use Java 7? Also, your reading code is broken

Comment: yes, Java 7. guys, im only changing 1 variable in the code, name of the file. everything else is the same. it working with hardcoded name of the file and don't with filenameToRead

Comment: Try printing out the full path of `myFile` variable. myFile.getAbsolutePath(). It will show u the file you're trying to access.

Comment: Normally the working directory is the project root. Try and just use `new File("ISBN 123-654.txt")` and put the file in your project root to see what happens.

Comment: here is the path printed out H:\Java\workspace\LMS\files\ISBN 111-222.txt

Comment: here is the error files\ISBN 111-222.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Is LMS the project root?

Comment: If you read the previous comments and really-really checked that "H:\Java\workspace\LMS\files\ISBN 111-222.txt" file really exists, then the only other reason for FNFE is that your application does not have a permission to read that file. But you did checked that it exists, didn't you?

Comment: thats right, but would it matter? i tried to use different pathes like String path = "H:\\Java\\workspace\\LMS\\files\\"; String path = "LMS\\files\\"; no difference

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: Yes Oleg. As im saying. im only changing the way a file name is representated, visually it looks the same. It working with hardcoded name "ISBN 123-654.txt", and dont with  filenameToRead(which is the same thing)

Comment: i use eclipse, running test class

Comment: i already gave permissions to project folders

Comment: In case nobody noticed, `ISBN 111-222.txt` is different from `ISBN 123-654.txt`. Your hard coded value and variable value are different. Have your variable value as `ISBN 123-654.txt` then rerun your test. Should behave the same as hardcoded.

Comment: hold on a minute... i think i got it. File name DOES give a different book name!

Comment: you are right, noticed it as well, i guess my result from arryalist is different

Comment: Great. Problem solved :).